# styled an e-mail in html, now how do i send it?

Tags: html, email

so i've made styled e-mail but now i don't know how to send it using gmail or any other e-mail platform. Apparently just copying and pasting the code into the e-mail doesn't work. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: What does this question have to do with programming?

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question! We have always used a whole tool-stack for these things (e.g. a CMS in which contents are edited and an mailing-tool, which would read the mail content from a URL provided by the CMS).

However, if you do it locally on your machine with Outlook, this link might help (just tried it and it works for me):
http://www.soltech-solutions.com/how-to-import-html-into-outlook-email.html

Note that creating HTML based mail that displays well on many platforms is quite a challenging task with many caveats.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new email, click on “Attach File”. Find your .html file, then, click on the drop down arrow next to “Insert”. Scroll down and click on “Insert as Text”.Your .html file should now be displayed in your e-mail as you were intending. Just make sure to test any of links, etc. before sending.

Comment: cant find the arrow.. there's just an x to delete the attachment

Comment: and wouldn't that be the same as just copying and pasting it in there?

Comment: You are looking in the wrong place for the arrow. Follow our steps carefully

Comment: I think you are inserting the file then trying to find the drop down arrow. The arrow appears on the pop up window you see once you click on “Attach File”.

Comment: nope there's just a button that says "open" and one that says "cancel". i'm using debian linux